# How to delete duplicates in line of text?

Tags: linux, string, sed, replace, duplicates

I can't find anything on how to do this. I read the documentation on uniq but it only deals with duplicate lines, I need to remove duplicate strings in the same line.

Let's say I have

```
TodayToday is an an array
```

I need it to ouput

```
Today is an array
```

Thanks!

Comment: check out this link may help you out https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-remove-delete-duplicate-lines-from-textfile-on-unix-linux

Comment: That deletes duplicate lines, I need to delete duplicate strings within the same line.

Comment: that would be a job for sed, not uniq.

Comment: That's great because all I've been using is sed to process this stuff, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: do the repeated characters need to be separated by a space and/or joined to be considered as a repetition, or do they have to be removed if repetitions of the same sequence of characters are found in any place of the same line?

Comment: Any place, I actually don't have any spaces within the line. I'm thinking I'm gonna have to do this manually, this is going way over my head :p

Comment: I am unsure what you mean, doing this `echo 'TodayToday is an an array' | sed -e 's/\([a-z]\+\)[^\1]\1/\1/g'` gives `Today is an array` in your provided test case.

Comment: That worked perfect. How do I make it case-insensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uniq` works on entire lines, the proper tool for processing the line contents is `sed` (you could use also `awk` or Perl for other ways of doing these one-liners).

Since you say in your comments that you already use `sed` and you tagged your question "linux", here is how you would obtain the repetition removal, with identical sequences of upper or lowercase, based on your provided test case using **GNU sed**:

```
$ echo 'TodayToday is an an array' | sed -e 's/\b\([a-zA-Z ]\+\)\1/\1/g'
Today is an array
```

if you want to treat "TodayTODay" as a repetition, then you could to this (add `i` case-insentitive flag):

```
$ echo 'TodayTODay is an an array' | sed -e 's/\b\([a-z ]\+\)\1/\1/gi'
Today is an array
```

if you want to treat groups of words separated by spaces such as "Today is an arrayToday is an array" as a repetition, you can do this (add space in the matching set):

```
$ echo 'Today is an arrayTODay is an array' | sed -e 's/\b\([a-z ]\+\)\1/\1/gi'
Today is an array
```

doing this, does not, nevertheless allow the regexp to decide not to alter a word such as "**nana**"

```
$ echo 'Her name was Nana' | sed -e 's/\b\([a-z ]\+\)\1/\1/gi'
Her name was Na
```

but we can safely say we eat "**banana**", given the `\b` word boundary introduced before the regexp to address the case drawn to our attention by @purplepsycho:

```
$ echo 'We eat banana' | sed -e 's/\b\([a-z ]\+\)\1/\1/gi'
We eat banana
```

Comment: Warning, you won't be able to say that your eating a *banana*

Comment: I have this `Wing AttackWing Attack` and it's not doing anything to this line.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover repeated sequences of multiple words adding the space character in the set, nevertheless, @purplepsycho is right, since you want to cover repeated sequences, whether or not separated by a space, there is no easy way to distinguish if "banana" or a person named "Nana" are sequences to be corrected.

Comment: `[^\1]` is not using the backreference, it's just "any character other than ``\`` or `1`", as ``\`` is not special within a character class.

Comment: @BenjaminW. right, but then removing that makes the proposed regexp to match "rr" in "array", and turn it into "aray"... I am unsure why. Another strategy would checking for word boundary at the beginning of the expression. That would address the case of "banana" (but still "Nana" would remain unsolved), I am updating the proposed answer with that.

Comment: GNU sed only that.

Comment: @dawg, yes the OP tagged his question "linux", anyway I will add this information, though I am unsure what in my proposed regexp would be specific to GNU sed.

Comment: `\b` is the GNU sed thing.  And maybe `\+`.

Comment: @stevesliva thanks, I see about the `\b` and possibly `\+` being GNU specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Ruby:

```
$ echo 'TodayToday is an an array' | ruby -lape 'gsub(/\b([a-zA-Z ]+)\1/, "\\1")'
Today is an array
```

Given the word boundary, it works with `banana`:

```
$ echo 'TodayToday is an an banana' | ruby -lape 'gsub(/\b([a-zA-Z ]+)\1/, "\\1")'
Today is an banana
```

Similarly with Perl:

```
$ echo 'TodayToday is an an banana' | perl -lape 's/\b([a-zA-Z ]+)\1/\1/g'
Today is an banana
```

Since it is essentially the same pattern as [Tardis' GNU sed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44949544/298607), the same observations apply.